# Error when use require in Meteor JS

Tags: authentication, meteor, oauth, token, jwt

when i use any package in my App for example (meteor add outatime:jwt-simple
) 
i tried `var jwt = Meteor.require('jwt-simple')`. 
In console have error 
**Error in OAuth Server: Meteor.require is not a function**. What right way for use package? That i am use in server side files. Is there difference between use require for package in server side or client side?

Answer (score 2):

According to the package documentation, you refer to it like this:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
```

This package is also available on npm, and this is a preferred way to use packages now (with Atmosphere you are dependent on updates from the atmosphere package author, and with npm you can get updates as they are published)

So you should be able to follow the Meteor documentation on how to use them:

> **Using npm Packages**
>
> To use an npm package from a file in your application you simply
>   import the name of the package:
>
> ```
> import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
>
> // this is equivalent to the standard node require (if the above doesn't work):
> const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
> ```

Source: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html

Either way you should then  be able to use jwt to do things, eg:

```
// encode 
var token = jwt.encode(payload, secret);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. I am use own package for auth (for example: accounts-github). And there in server side i want use jwt-decode. I write `import jwt from 'jwt-simple';` in the top and `const jwt = require('jwt-simple');` in one of my function but i am get this error: [error from CLI](http://image.prntscr.com/image/e58d4023d2ce4a628897c154f3b1fb30.png)

Comment: If it is complaining about "import", it means that it is not supporting ES6 - Some server functions run plain javascript, so you should use the "require" syntax there

Comment: you mean write: `Meteor.require('jwt-simple')`, but this cause the error (

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems with different library and i used Meteor.npmRequire instead of require to solve issue. Please try Meteor.npmRequire('jwt-simple').

Best regards,

Dino